# How to export data from Mongo DB to excel format in java

Tags: java, mongodb

Schema in MongoDB:
{
    "Name" : "Kamala",
    "Flows" : [

```
    {
        "Date" : "2018-08-03",
        "New" : "set",
        "Form" : {
            "y" : "1",
            "d" : "3",
            "p" : "3"
        }
    }
]
```

}

my java code:
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
     String db = "Database";
     String col = "col";
     String Host="localhost";
     String Port="27017";
     String fileName = "D:/File/sample.xls";

     String Query = "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.4\\bin\\mongoexport.exe --host " + Host + " --port " + Port + " --db " + db + " --collection " + col + " --type=xls--fields Name,Flows, --out " + fileName + "";

     try {
         System.out.println(Query);

         StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(Query);
         String[] Queryarray = new String[st.countTokens()];
         for (int i = 0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
             Queryarray[i] = st.nextToken();

         ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Queryarray);
         processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

         Process process = processBuilder.start();
         BufferedReader processOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

         String data = "";
         while ((data = processOutput.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(data);
         }


     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

I am trying to retrieve the date,new,Form Values inside the Flows array

Comment: SO is not a free code delivery community. What have you tried you need to explain with code? Please take some time to read the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can look at the link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/mongodb/mongodb-import-export-json-data-example/